# Spring Boot with embedded ActiveMQ Artemis JMS server

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I'm customizing the embedded ActiveMQ Artemis server using the code below.

```java
@Override
public void customize(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration)
```

It works fine, and I figured out I can access later on like this ->

```java
Queue queue =  embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().locateQueue("queue");

QueueControl queueControl = new QueueControlImpl(queue,
                queue.getAddress().toString(),embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer(),embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getStorageManager()              ,embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getSecurityStore(),embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getAddressSettingsRepository());

queueControl.browse();
```

Is there a problem doing like this?

I'm trying to write a custom endpoint to handle the queue management instead of using the classical package with Jolokia.

Comment: Yes! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking there isn't really a *problem* doing this, but there may be better ways of doing what you want. For example, to get a `QueueControl` instance you can do something like this:

```java
QueueControl queueControl = embeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer().getManagementService().getResource(ResourceNames.QUEUE + "queue");
```

This will get the `QueueControl` which was *already* created for the queue rather than creating a new one from scratch.