# How to config max-delivery-attempts for Spring Boot with Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis, spring-boot-starter

I would like to config the `max-delivery-attempts` of dead letter as described in [the manual](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/undelivered-messages.html).

I tried [Spring Boot with embedded ActiveMQ Artemis JMS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408568/spring-boot-with-embedded-activemq-artemis-jms-server), but cannot figure out how to set `max-delivery-attempts` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging the `Configuration` instance I finally find the method. Here's the code:

```java
@Configuration
public class RedeliveryConfiguration implements ArtemisConfigurationCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.config.Configuration configuration) {
        Map<String, AddressSettings> addressesSettings = configuration.getAddressesSettings();

        // # is the catch all address or default address
        addressesSettings.get("#").setMaxDeliveryAttempts(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help others who have this same question in the future. Thanks!